# SQl Server - Calcular promedio entre varias columnas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla, la cual tiene valores de ventas totales segun meses:

| venta01 | venta02 | venta03 | venta04 | venta05 | venta06 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 250 | 130 | 11 | 45 | 62 | 96 |
| 15 | 333 | 643 | 50 | 55 | 75 |

Lo que necesito es poder sacar el promedio de estas 6 columnas de alguna forma mas sencilla, ya que actualmente lo realizo a "mano":

```
(SUM(venta01 + venta02 + venta03 + venta04 + venta05 + venta06) / 6)
```

He estado trantando de ver algun metodo con AVG, pero no logro encontrar algo que me ayude.

Comment: Creo que sería más fácil si tuvieses las ventas registradas en filas y no en columnas podrías usar AVG haciendo una agrupación por tipo de venta. Algo como: registro1, venta1, 250; registro2, venta2, 130; ...

Comment: No, no hay otra forma, el `avg` trabaja verticalmente y no horizontalmente. ¿Qué es realmente lo que te molesta de la forma en que estás haciendo el promedio?

Comment: Tu código no está sacando el promedio, está sacando la suma de filas y columnas para luego dividirlo entre 6. El resultado es cercano a la suma de promedios, pero no es el promedio real.

Comment: Luis, a que te refieres con que no es el calculo real? Me puedes explicar?